# Configuring Laravel 5 Unit Test URL with phpunit.xml

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I've been running a lot of tests fine, but one, where the route generates a url keeps failing.

After inspection it looks like it's using a default APP_URL.

I've changed it in phpunit.xml but it makes no difference (even after clearing the cache)

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="APP_URL" value="http://local.dev:8888"/>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Any help? Bet it's something stupid!

Thanks

Comment: How are you running your phpunit? By that I mean which args?

Comment: No Args @FelippeDuarte. Just using `vendor/bin/phpunit` should i use args for my xml to take effect?

Comment: use phpunit -c path/to/xml . See more here: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/textui.html#textui.clioptions

Answer (score -1):

In `/tests/TestCase.php`

Change the $baseUrl value.

```
/**
 * The base URL to use while testing the application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $baseUrl = 'http://my-local-domain.dev';
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the $baseUrl value in TestCase class in root of test directory.
Here sample provided. All other values will be masked by this.

```
abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://local.dev:8888';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {

    }


}
```